# How to speed up code to search many sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have active sheet open (Sheet1). I want to pick a value from C column then go through each workbook and within each workbook there are many sheets. If that value (value from C column of active sheet) matches anywhere in that workbook in any sheet then update in active sheet R column saying found otherwise no update.

Sheet1 has 95000 rows.
book3.xlsx has many sheets which totals 34000 rows.
book4.xlsx too has many rows which totals 24000 rows.
Takes around 4 hours to complete.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Found()
Dim NumberOfValues1, NumberOfValues2, NumberOfValues3 As Integer
Dim i, n, o As Long
Dim wb1, wb2 As Workbook
Dim wbsb1, worksheet1, worksheet2 As Worksheet
Dim newExcel As Excel.Application
Set newExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim value1, value2, value3 As String
    
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\commvault2\book3.xlsx")
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\commvault2\book4.xlsx")
Application.ScreenUpdating = FALSE 
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
   
NumberOfValues1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
Set wbsb1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

For i = 2 To NumberOfValues1
    value1 = wbsb1.Range("C" & i).Value
    For Each worksheet1 In wb1.Worksheets
        NumberOfValues2 = worksheet1.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
        For n = 1 To NumberOfValues2
            value2 = worksheet1.Cells(n, 1)
            If value1 = value2 Then
                wbsb1.Range("R" & i).Value = "Found"
            End If
        Next
    Next
            
    For Each worksheet2 In wb2.Worksheets
        NumberOfValues3 = worksheet2.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
        For o = 1 To NumberOfValues3
            value3 = worksheet2.Cells(o, 1)
            If value1 = value3 Then
                wbsb1.Range("R" & i).Value = "Found"
            End If
        Next
    Next
Next 
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

wb1.Close
wb2.Close
newExcel.Quit
Set newExcel = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: If the code is working then Code Review is where you should post.

Comment: Will you use column `R` for both workbooks, i.e. if it is found in `wb1`, no need to search for it in `wb2`?

Comment: Hi VBasic2008 , that is good idea. yes once found in wb1 then i don't want to search same in wb2. can you help me re-write code ?

Comment: Once you've written "found" you can exit the loop - no point in writing it to the same cell multiple times...  But `Match()` would be a lot faster than looping.   Also you declare and create `newExcel` but you never use it?   For those who voted to close, I'm not sure why this is closed as "Opinion Based" - granted I do have "opinions" on how it could be restructured to run faster, but not sure why those are unwanted....

Comment: I'll have to agree with Tim. I've created a solution and cannot post. So we're waiting for one more vote for your question to be reopened.

Comment: A different approach (untested though)  https://docs.google.com/document/d/18LEHta_Q6DBjJSSlKrdHdvFC6LqpFS5dv7FUJTlfS-o/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Tim Williams: I had to take a peek. Nice. Could you share why the `Goto` is OK? For comparison, I used a boolean `FoundAll`, and at the end of each of the loops I had to use `If FoundAll = True Then Exit For`. Maybe I've answered my own question.

Comment: @VBasic2008 - I think breaking out of nested loops is an acceptable use of Goto: it's "intended use" vs. abuse/overuse in place of regular flow control.

Answer (score 1):

### Check Matches

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CheckMatches()
    
    ' Source
    Dim sFolderPath As String: sFolderPath = "C:\commvault2\"
    Const sFileNamesList As String = "Book3.xlsx,Book4.xlsx" ' no spaces!
    Const slCol As String = "A" ' Lookup Column
    Const sfRow As Long = 1 ' suspicious, possibly 2
    ' Destination
    Const dwsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dlCol As String = "C" ' Lookup Column
    Const dvCol As String = "R" ' Value Column
    Const dfRow As Long = 2
    Const dvString As String = "Found"
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(dwsName)
    
    Dim dlRow As Long: dlRow = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, dlCol).End(xlUp).Row
    If dlRow < dfRow Then Exit Sub ' no data in column
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = dlRow - dfRow + 1 ' Rows Count
    Dim dlrg As Range: Set dlrg = dws.Cells(dfRow, dlCol).Resize(drCount)
    
    Dim Data As Variant ' Destination Lookup and Value Array
    If drCount = 1 Then
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data = dlrg.Value
    Else
        Data = dlrg.Value
    End If
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim dKey As Variant
    Dim dr As Long
    For dr = 1 To drCount
        dKey = Data(dr, 1)
        If Not IsError(dKey) Then
            If Len(dKey) > 0 Then
                If Not dict.Exists(dKey) Then
                    Set dict(dKey) = New Collection ' to cover for duplicates
                End If
                dict(dKey).Add dr ' array row numbers
            End If
        End If
    Next dr
    If dict.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub ' only error values or blanks
    
    ReDim Data(1 To drCount, 1 To 1) ' clear destination array
    
    If Right(sFolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then sFolderPath = sFolderPath & "\"
    Dim sFileNames() As String: sFileNames = Split(sFileNamesList, ",")
    Dim nUpper As String: nUpper = UBound(sFileNames)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim swb As Workbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    Dim slrg As Range ' Lookup (Column) Range
    Dim slRow As Long ' Last Row
    Dim srCount As Long ' Rows Count
    Dim sFilePath As String ' File Path
    Dim cItem As Variant ' Collection Item
    Dim n As Long
    Dim FoundAll As Boolean ' No More Dictionary Keys Flag
    
    For n = 0 To nUpper ' loop through workbook names
        sFilePath = sFolderPath & sFileNames(n)
        If Len(Dir(sFilePath)) > 0 Then ' file exists
            Set swb = Workbooks.Open(sFilePath)
            For Each sws In swb.Worksheets
                slRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, slCol).End(xlUp).Row
                If slRow >= sfRow Then
                    srCount = slRow - sfRow + 1
                    Set slrg = sws.Cells(sfRow, slCol).Resize(srCount)
                    For Each dKey In dict.Keys ' loop through the dict. keys
                        If IsNumeric(Application.Match(dKey, slrg, 0)) Then
                            ' Loop through each item (row) of the collection
                            For Each cItem In dict(dKey)
                                Data(cItem, 1) = dvString
                            Next cItem
                            dict.Remove dKey
                            If dict.Count = 0 Then
                                FoundAll = True
                                Exit For
                            'Else ' there are still elements in the dictionary
                                'Debug.Print Join(dict.Keys, ",")
                            End If
                        'Else ' match not found
                        End If
                    Next dKey
                    If FoundAll Then Exit For
                'Else ' no data in column
                End If
            Next sws
            swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        'Else ' file not found
        End If
        If FoundAll Then Exit For
    Next n
          
    ' Write to destination value range ('dvrg').
    Dim dvrg As Range: Set dvrg = dlrg.EntireRow.Columns(dvCol)
    dvrg.Value = Data
    
    Dim msgString As String: msgString = "Matches checked."
    If dict.Count > 0 Then
        msgString = msgString & vbLf & vbLf & _
            "Could not find the following items:" & vbLf & Join(dict.Keys, vbLf)
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox msgString, vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi ..VBasics2008, This code way above my head. is there way you can be more descriptive ?  i ran your script but it did not populate R column in active sheet.

Comment: Where is the `ActiveSheet` (what is its name) and where is the code located (both in which workbook)? Do you use a `Personal.xlsb` workbook?

Comment: code located in workbook where sheet1 exists. active sheet is sheet1. this workbook is open ( book2.xlsx) while other workbooks (book3 and book4) is closed.

Comment: Does this *matches anywhere in that workbook in any sheet* mean that you don't want to just search in column `A` (like in your code) of all of the worksheets of the source workbooks but you also want to search in other columns?

Comment: I want column A in all sheets in workbook book3 and book4 to be matched with column C from sheet1 , if match then report in sheet1 in working sheet column R as Found.

Comment: getting message run time error '1004' , application defined or object defind error at line "xStrAddress = Cells(1, xColumn).Address & ":" & Cells(xIntRox, xColumn).Address"  ...any idea ?

Comment: You need to add the worksheet variable, e.g. `xStrAddress = Worksheet1.Cells(1, xColumn).Address & ":" & Worksheet1.Cells(xIntRox, xColumn).Address`.

Answer (score 1):

Using Match():

```vb
Sub Found()

    Dim wb As Workbook, c As Range, wbsb1 As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim colWB As New Collection, i As Long, v, m
    
    'add workbooks to be searched to the Collection
    colWB.Add Workbooks.Open("C:\commvault2\book3.xlsx")
    colWB.Add Workbooks.Open("C:\commvault2\book4.xlsx")
    '...can add more wb here...
    
    Set wbsb1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    For Each c In wbsb1.Range("C2:C" & wbsb1.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row).Cells
        v = Trim(c.Value)
        If Len(v) > 0 Then
            For Each wb In colWB                  'loop opened workbooks
                For Each ws In wb.Worksheets      'loop sheets
                    m = Application.Match(v, ws.Columns("A"), 0) 'faster than looping or Find()
                    If Not IsError(m) Then        'if got no match `m` would be an error value
                        c.EntireRow.Columns("R").Value = "Found"
                        GoTo nextValue            'an OK use of Goto...
                    End If
                Next ws
            Next wb
        End If
nextValue:
    Next c
    
    'close all opened workbooks
    For i = colWB.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set wb = colWB(i)
        wb.Close False
    Next
      
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I am almost sure, the main problem is caused by

`NumberOfValues1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row`

It refers to the last cell/row of the column "A"...
Due to this, your code takes all the values in the whole column to perform matching... that means with most empty cells...
more than a million empty values...
try  changing to:

```
NumberOfValues1 =ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

the same with NumberOfValues2 and NumberOfValues3

Comment: can you explain "ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row" ?

Comment: it relates to range you set up for loop `For i = 2 To NumberOfValues1`
the code `.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` 
will find the last non-empty cell in the column, so you will reduce the amount of loops drastically....
lets say, the last value is entered into A15 cell, 
`.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` will give you value 15, 
so at the end Loop will be restricted to `For i = 2 To 15`

in your current code `For i = 2 To 1048576`

Comment: Getting compile error at" .Rows.count" . It should be "Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row" no dot before Rows.count  ..correct ?

Comment: yep, correct, will adjust the answer accordingly... - sorry was typing without testing...

Comment: you may have also problem if there is no data in the column, - you may get error...
better to introduce lrow variable (for last row) and start the loop after 'if lrow >1 then' statement

Comment: just tested old code "Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row" and i see only show 90046 rows so its not going all the way down.

Comment: Is it always like this in each worksheet? As you have 'For Each worksheet2 In wb2.Worksheets'

Comment: every worksheet has different number of rows , ran test on few and they are  6908 and 11236.

Comment: I was expecting your code runs into the empty column an this causes the code to freeze for next 4 hours...

Comment: Just take one value and check how long looping takes... Possibly you simply have too much data to match and maybe simple new column with match formula will do the trick faster... Or passing list of values to the Varisble and filter the target table based on that large list variable and move from there